# Block URL by VPN

Tags: browser, vpn, proxy, url

I am using an MDM (Mobile Device Management) service that has a web filtering option built inside the management console.

[image: This is the console]

The problem is it can block URLs only on the browser level (like Chrome or Firefox), so you can still get around and view unwanted sites via the app's inner browser. The MDM service also has a VPN function and a global HTTP proxy, I need to know if it will be possible to block URLs completely via VPN or HTTP proxy. I don't know exactly what is VPN or HTTP proxy is, but someone told me it could do it.

Or someone has another idea?